# Changing Text color animation in Android

Tags: android, textview, text-to-speech

I want to display a text paragraph(in black color) and a "PLAY" button. When the user clicks on "PLAY" button, it should start speaking(TTS) the text sentence by sentence alongside it should change the spoken text color to green (character by character)
Any suggestions appreciated... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [TextSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html)

See these tutorials / examples. They will help you get started:

1. http://www.example8.com/category/view/id/15552
2. http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/02/textswitching-animation-in-android-or-textswitcher-control-in-android/
3. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsesaTextSwitcher.htm

And finally, I believe an example is also available in the API demos from the **Samples For SDK** (API 13 I think) package in the *SDK Manager*

You will naturally have to code for synchronizing the TTS speech and the animation itself.

Comment: Thanks buddy. But, synchronizing TextSwitcher with TTS is a challenge for me :)

Comment: @Manjunath: Unfortunately, I have absolutely no experience with TTS. :-(

Comment: @Manjunath: I could have helped with the TextSwitcher, but TTS is a no-go. Sorry. :-(

Comment: Hey no probs dude... I have used TextSwitcher even before no worries... I am striving hard for TTS synchronization... :)